# boxsize in html using css

Tags: html, css

I have some problems with sizing boxes.
Here goes the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
      .wrapper { 

        text-align: center; 
      } 

      #bubble { 
        display: inline; 

        -moz-border-radius: 15px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        margin: 5px;
        width: 100px; 
        height: 100px; 
        position: relative; 
        border: solid;
        border-width: 1px; 
        background-color: #999999;
        font-name: arial;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper"> 
      <div id="bubble">Box 6</div> 
      <br clear="all"> 
      <div id="bubble">Box 5</div> 
      <div id="bubble">Box 5</div> 
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

So my problem is, I want the boxes to be 100px x 100px how mentioned in the style. But somehow chrome shows me 42px x 19px sized boxes.

Probably there is a simple thing I'm missing.
-.-°

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You've got invalid HTML: an `id` ***must be unique within the document***, that's not the (whole of the) problem. Though I'm not seeing an obvious reason why those dimensions would be reported. Ah, yes: `inline` >.<

Comment: Change `display:inline;` to `display:inline-block;` and it should work. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b64cs/)

Comment: I have created a fiddle with what you would like to achieve. And added also the right dimension 100x100px circles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can not use id for multiple element, switch that to class.
2. you should change your display to inline-block or block, for the width / height to work.

hope this help.

```
 .wrapper { 

    text-align: center; 
  } 

  .bubble { 
    display: inline-block; 

    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    position: relative; 
    border: solid;
    border-width: 1px; 
    background-color: #999999;
    font-name: arial;
  }
```

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/N8meT/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
display: inline;
```

with this

```
display: inline-block;
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6dLFz/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Change the #bubble's `display` to inline-block, which will create a block element and it will therefore receive your desired dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

this might help

```
#bubble { 
    display: inline-block; 
    vertical-align: top;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    position: relative; 
    border: solid;
    border-width: 1px; 
    background-color: #999999;
    font-name: arial;
  }
```

please see the [codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vwJga)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `display:inline;` with `display:inline-block;`

Also to achieve 100x100px you could use:

```
 *, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mBBJM/4553/

If you inspect every circle you will see the actual dimensions are 100px x 100px.